# How do I log in as root?

Tags: permissions, root, aptitude

How do I log in as root?  I can't use aptitude unless I am root.
I have broken / held packages that I can't install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really log in as root directly, but you can use sudo. `sudo -i` gives you a root prompt, and putting `sudo` before a command runs it as root. The root account by default on ubuntu is designed to avoid people logging in for security reasons, and also probably because `sudo` does that task of logging in as root for you - why create extra work for yourself? ;)